# Ionic-Angular android app no funciona bien en versiones menores a 7

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic

He creado una app que obtiene coordenadas en ionic y cordova que funciona perfectamente para versiones de android 7 o superiores pero cuando corro la app en android 6 o menos la app carga pero los botones no aparecen(solo el texto de los botones se ve) guarda los mensajes y todo pero no guarda las coordenadas, cosa que en la base de datos me queda longuitud:null latitud:null y mensaje:'mensaje'. Necesito correr la aplicacion en android desde 6 para arriba pero no puedo con la version 6, alguien sabe porque no se puede? El sdk es version 28 y la minima es 19, la version de cordova-android es 8 que revisando la tabla https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html debe abarcar versiones de android desde 4.4 hasta 9 APIs(19-28) y la plataforma que se instala al correr $ionic cordova platform add android es 8, he intentado instalarle otras versiones y la 7 funciona bien(ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0) pero al hacerlo con la version 6 me sale error al agregar la plataforma

Comment: Y cuál es el error que te marca exactamente al hacer build para Android versión inferior a 7?, O no te sale ningún error?

Comment: @Riven Disculpa la tardanza, no sale ningun error, simplemente los componentes no aparecen y las coordenadas no se guardan, fuera de eso la app corre bien, hace login bien, el registro funciona pero no se ven los botones y las coordenadas no se guardan, solo es eso

Comment: Hola, pienso que para poder saber que esta pasando seria buena idea que mostraras parte del codigo html donde añades los botones, o en caso de que hagas alguna modificacion a los botones desde tu pagina.ts, mostrar esa parte en la que hiciste eso, de otra manera no es tan sencillo hacer un debug.

Comment: Por otro lado me gustaria saber si para obtener esas coordenadas usas GoogleMaps?, y si es asi, si usas la SDK de google maps y no el script de javascript para ello, ya que si no estoy mal el SDK de google maps no funciona muy bien, o por lo menos no en ionic... a mi me paso que usando la SDK de google maps por alguna razon la aplicacion me cambia a fondo blanco en la pagina donde lo uso, aparte el mapa queda estatico (Inmovil) y aparte no muestra error alguno, podria ser que te pase algo parecido a lo que hace poco me paso pero con tus botones??

Comment: @Riven saludos, me disculpo por la tardanza, te comento que el código no era el problema, es un problema de ionic que tenia con las versiones anteriores de android.. proble de version 7 en adelante y corre bien, ademas lo necesitaba para version 7 asi que ya no tengo ningun problema con las versiones, muchas gracias por tu ayuda